# Can cutting the stem, green raspberry berries ripen in water

Tags: cuttings, raspberries, berries, ripening

Can different kinds of raspberries, be cut and ripen if the berry is green in water? Cuttings Before the frost hits. Thank you.

Comment: That seems unlikely, but I've never tried it. I have covered the plants when there's  a short-term frost/freeze and it seems likley they'll get a few more weeks. With a forecast like my area has now (froze last night, will freeze colder the next 3-4 nights) I just say it's the end of the season and let them go.